# Android: In app billing, using library or not?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have just created the Android in-app billing example from the docs, and its all working well. When it comes to implementing the examples code into my own application it all seems very complicated / scary. I'm unsure whether to go ahead with it without fully understanding how it works. Has anyone used this library? [Android in-app billing library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary)

How reliable and stable is that code? Anyone encountered any problems?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this library is being used and yes, you are right about it being scary. Look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134578/1124861) to see how others are tackling this challenge.

Also, there is another, simpler, tutorial example code. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the library.

> Has anyone used this library?

Yes, many people do. That is a good thing because it reduces the likelihood of major bugs. And a bad thing because it makes your app more vulnerable to bypass billing.

> How reliable and stable is that code?

Check it out yourself. If you don't understand the code, you shouldn't be using it anyway.

In any case, using the library as a starting point should be better than starting from scratch.

> Anyone encountered any problems?

Check out the [issues](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).

Comment: are you releasing the fix for issue #52 soon? Or should I just get your patch.

Comment: Soonish. I expect to update the library with this and many other improvements towards the end of the month.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *know* what that library you linked to is doing, it's a simple matter of going through the source code and figuring it out (it's all available on Github!). Now if you don't *want* to figure out what exactly it's doing, then frankly speaking you should not be implementing it in your app.

Stick with the examples from [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html) and you should be fine.

Also, polling for *opinions* on that library is a no-no on Stack Overflow :)

Another thing I should point out. From the [README](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/README.mdown) file in the library you linked to:

> **Disclaimer**
>
> This library is a very early release and it should not be used as
>   production code.

Comment: I mentioned the library due to the publisher on another SO post stated that you could request and check with only a few methods as opposed to many with the google example. I feel you are being negative!

Comment: @Jon I apologize if I come across as negative, but I'm just stating facts (i.e. the disclaimer, etc). Rule of thumb is _never_ use code from the Internet that you don't fully understand. Now if you choose not to listen, then by all means go ahead. Good luck :)

Comment: @Jonno I wrote the library and I don't think Marvin Pinto is being negative.